# unordered_map emplace compile error

Tags: c++, unordered-map, emplace

I have the following code in *myclass.h* file:

```
typedef std::unordered_set< int, int> Parameters;
class MyClass
{
    public:
        void myFunction();
    private:
        Parameters* m_params;
}
```

Then, *myFunction* looks as follows:

```
void MyClass::myFunction()
{
    ...
    m_params->emplace(1,1);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get:

*term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments*

If I comment the *emplace* line, the error disappears. However, I don't find any misuse related to this function signature:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `std::unordered_set != std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo: You used `std::unordered_set` in your code, but you meant `std::unordered_map`.

Your implementation doesn't recognise any error setting `Hash` to `int` in the [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) template until you try to put something into the container. Then it tries to hash the input, and realises it can't use an `int` as a function.

Comment: Time to take a break then! Likely you will make an error that the compiler won't save you from, and will bite you in the arse later.